# How to implement a LowPass Filter?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, signal-processing

I'm doing some math on both gyroscope and accelerometer data combined and I'd like to low pass filter the resulting data. So could someone post some generic code for a Low Pass filter?

Comment: do you want the code to generate coefficients or just perform the filtering? should it be an IIR or an FIR filter?

Comment: Well I'd like a filter similar to what Apple uses to filter the accelerometer data. Only their code doesn't work for me.

Comment: in what way does it not work?

Comment: well it seems that I need to pass in UIAccelerometer struct (Which i'm not using), unless that's just a struct that holds the current accelerometer values?

Comment: UIAcceleration is just a struct containing the current values for each axis of the accelerometer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 1st order IIR low-pass filter can be of the form:

```
output_value = rate * input_value + (1.0 - rate) * previous_output_value;
```

which is pretty much what's inside Apple's AccelerometerGraph example.  You select the rate parameter depending on what frequency (very very roughly shakes per second) you want to roll-off or start to attenuate to get a smoother resulting output, and the sample rate of the input data.

Answer (score 2):

A low pass filter is simply smoothing of the results to remove the high frequencies.  The simplest low pass filter is a box filter which is done by averaging n samples together.

For averaging 2 samples together this is as simple as doing:

```
sample[n] (sample[n] + sample[n + 1]) / 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If Apple's [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) example is too complex for you to understand, I created a simpler accelerometer example for my class which you can download [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AccelerometerExample.zip).  This implements a simple low-pass and high-pass filter for raw accelerometer values, then logs the results to the screen.

As hotpaw2 and Goz describe, this uses a very simple weighted rolling average for the filter calculation:

```
UIAccelerationValue lowPassFilteredXAcceleration = (currentXAcceleration * kLowPassFilteringFactor) + (previousLowPassFilteredXAcceleration * (1.0 - kLowPassFilteringFactor));
```